# libcurl pipelining -- add a new url while multi perform is underway

Tags: libcurl, pipelining

Let's say you have this

```
curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_multi_add_handle(pCurlMulti, pCurl);
curl_multi_perform(...)
```

// now we are waiting for response from the server
// while waiting, could we call

```
curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_URL, newUrl);
```

// without curl_multi_remove_handle & curl_multi_add_handle?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't change the URL of an active transfer. Instead, [enable pipelining on the multi handle](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLMOPT_PIPELINING.html) and then add one easy handle for each transfer; the multi handle will pipeline the requests over the same connection if possible.

Comment: thank you for your response. So if I have to queue up a new request while previous one is still pending, create a new easy handle with new url and add to multi? is that the best way to do it?

Comment: Yes, and if the server supports pipelining (and you've enabled that option for the multi handle) then they'll automatically share the same connection.

Comment: Note though that if both ends can do HTTP/2, you can ask curl to do multiplexing (using the same option) and then the subsequent transfers can start immediately and be done in parallel.

Comment: Thank you Andrew and Daniel